# ASP.NET Core - getting a message back from AuthenticationHandler

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core

I have implemented a subclass of `AuthenticationHandler`. It returns `AuthenticationResult.Fail("This is why you can't log in");`

I would have expected this message to end up in the body, or at least in the HTTP status text, but instead I get a blank 401 response.

Is there any way to provide additional information for failed authentication attempts in ASP.NET core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the body or Http status, you could try `Context.Response`.

Here is a demo code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
namespace TestIdentity
{
    public class CustomAuthenticationHandler<TOptions> : AuthenticationHandler<TOptions> where TOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions, new()
    {
        public CustomAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<TOptions> options
            , ILoggerFactory logger
            , UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {

        }
        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            await Context.Response.WriteAsync("This is why you can't log in");
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("This is why you can't log in");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this did cross my mind, but it seems unclean to be directly writing to the response in a handler like this. Does that mean that the framework actually provides no way to achieve this?

Comment: When I add `Context.Response.WriteAsync()` I get "StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started". Moreover, StatusCode comes out as 200 instead of 401. Not sure if something changed between above answer and Core 3.1.

Comment: This is changing the status code to 200,  hence we can't get the real http response which we need to get

Comment: IMO this is an unclean solution and even if you want to do it here (in the handler) you would need to implement it in overrides of `HandleForbiddenAsync`/`HandleChallengeAsync` and modify the `Response` after the `base` is called (which modifies the `StatusCode` - see here https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs,266).

Answer (score 11):

Override HandleChallengeAsync:

In the example below the `failReason` is a private field in my implementation of AuthenticationHandler. 
I don't know if this is the best way to pass the reason for failure. But the `AuthenticationProperties` on the `AuthenticateResult.Fail` method did not make it through to `HandleChallengeAsync` in my test.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler<TOptions> : AuthenticationHandler<TOptions> where TOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions, new()
{
    private string failReason;

    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<TOptions> options
        , ILoggerFactory logger
        , UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        failReason = "Reason for auth fail";
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail(failReason);
    }

    protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 401;

        if (failReason != null)
        {
            Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = failReason;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> Override this method to deal with 401 challenge concerns, if an authentication scheme in question deals an authentication interaction as part of it's request flow. (like adding a response header, or changing the 401 result to 302 of a login page or external sign-in location.)

Source:
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L201

Comment: What is the purpose of passing a string to AuthenticateResult.Fail? Is it not used by anything?

Comment: @Omiron it appears to be this way by design - the message string would be used for internal logging purposes. See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4865 To be fair, 401 is self-explanatory though I get wanting to return a message rather than a blank HTML document in the case of a web browser.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you should write to the response's body of a failed custom `AuthenticationHandler` by overriding its `HandleChallengeAsync` method:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace OpenAPISwaggerDoc.Web.Authentication;

public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private string _failReason;

    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
        {
            _failReason = "Missing Authorization header";
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(_failReason));
        }

        try
        {
            var authenticationHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationHeader.Parameter);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(':');
            var username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];

            if (string.Equals(username, "DNT", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                string.Equals(password, "123", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username) };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
            }

            _failReason = "Invalid username or password";
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(_failReason));
        }
        catch
        {
            _failReason = "Invalid Authorization header";
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(_failReason));
        }
    }

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);
        if (Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_failReason))
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", _failReason);
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await WriteProblemDetailsAsync(_failReason);
        }
    }

    private Task WriteProblemDetailsAsync(string detail)
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails { Detail = detail, Status = Context.Response.StatusCode };
        var result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
                     {
                         ContentTypes = new MediaTypeCollection(),
                         StatusCode = problemDetails.Status,
                         DeclaredType = problemDetails.GetType(),
                     };
        var executor = Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>>();
        var routeData = Context.GetRouteData() ?? new RouteData();
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(Context, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());
        return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this code in my custom Middleware to return **problemDetails** response.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    await this.Next(httpContext);

    if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)
    {
        var authenticateResult = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

        if (authenticateResult.Failure != null)
        {
            var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData() ?? new RouteData();
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

            var problemDetails = this.ProblemDetailsFactory.CreateProblemDetails(httpContext,
                statusCode: httpContext.Response.StatusCode,
                detail: authenticateResult.Failure.Message);

            var result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
            {
                ContentTypes = new MediaTypeCollection(),
                StatusCode = problemDetails.Status,
                DeclaredType = problemDetails.GetType()
            };

            await this.Executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
        }
    }
}
```