# ASP.NET Core - getting a message from AuthenticateResult.Fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, error-handling

Can not get an error message in HTTP response.

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(checkTokenResponse.Error))
            {
                Logger.LogError(checkTokenResponse.Error);
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(checkTokenResponse.Error);
            }
```

response

[image]

I suppose the error message should render into *data* response field
The same question [ASP.NET Core - getting a message back from AuthenticationHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834452/asp-net-core-getting-a-message-back-from-authenticationhandler)

**Update**

code of custom Auth handler

```
public class AuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions>
{
    private readonly IPrimeApiProxy _primeApiProxy;
    private readonly IPrimeProxy _primeProxy;
    private readonly int _adminGroupId;

    private static readonly string HeaderName = "Authorization";
    private static readonly string ApiAuthScheme = "oauth ";

    public AuthHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock,
        IPrimeApiProxy primeApiProxy,
        IPrimeProxy primeProxy,
        ApplicationSettingsProvider settings)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _primeApiProxy = primeApiProxy ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(primeApiProxy));
        _primeProxy = primeProxy ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(primeProxy));

        _adminGroupId = int.Parse((settings as dynamic).AdminGroupId as string);
    }


    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        Logger.LogTrace("HandleAuthenticateAsync");

        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");
        }

        try
        {
            var token = FetchToken(Request);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.token) && token.userId < 1)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Invalid token");
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid token");
            }

            var checkTokenResponse = await _primeProxy.CheckToken(token.token);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(checkTokenResponse.Error))
            {
                Logger.LogError(checkTokenResponse.Error);
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(checkTokenResponse.Error);
            }

            var isValidInt = int.TryParse(checkTokenResponse.UserId, out var userId);

            if (!isValidInt)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("User Id is invalid");
            }

            if (token.userId != userId)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("The token belongs to another user");
            }

            bool isUserAdminAndCustomGroupMember = false;
            
            if (checkTokenResponse.UserRole == "admin")
            {
                isUserAdminAndCustomGroupMember = await _primeApiProxy.IsGroupMember(token.token, token.userId, _adminGroupId);
            }

            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, token.userId.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, isUserAdminAndCustomGroupMember ? "Admin" : "Learner")
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, "Auth exception");
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header");
        }
    }

    private static (string token, int userId) FetchToken(HttpRequest request)
    {
        string authHeader = request.Headers[HeaderName];

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith(ApiAuthScheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            string token = authHeader.Substring(ApiAuthScheme.Length).Trim();
            string[] parts = token.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (int.TryParse(parts[1], out int userId))
            {
                return (parts[0], userId);
            }
        }

        return (null, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you do this instead: `return Unauthorized(checkTokenResponse.Error);`

Comment: It seems that you are creating a custom AuthenticationHandler right? Can you post enough code reproduce the problem, it is better for us to reproduce the problem and give   some suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I can not use Unauthorized class because I oblige to return AuthenticateResult type from my Auth Handler. Update code, see above.

Comment: @ZhiLv I've updated the code snippet. Please find above **HandleAuthenticateAsync** overriding method implementation.

Comment: @ArtemBeziazychnyi Did you happen to find a solution? If so, can you post it as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I realise that a lot of time has passed since the problem. Today, I wanted to share the solution I produced myself because I encountered a similar problem.

I made a `Fail` return in the handler

```cs
return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorised");
```

After that I found the solution by checking under Action as follows.

```cs
if(!User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
{
   return Unauthorised();
}
```